# Nuevo "comentario" en una antigua "pregunta"

Tags: soporte

explico mi duda.
Realicé una pregunta hace meses:

[¿Qué alternativas puedo tener a utilizar una base de datos para este caso?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6322/qu%c3%a9-alternativas-puedo-tener-a-utilizar-una-base-de-datos-para-este-caso)

Ahora he vuelto sobre el tema y he realizado un "comentario" para preguntar una duda sobre una de las respuestas que recibí.

Al pinchar en el botón "Preguntas" de la página principal (es decir, yendo a https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions), mi pregunta no aparece en las últimas. Es decir, que parece que añadir un nuevo "comentario" no hace subir una pregunta al principio en la lista.

Entonces mi pregunta aquí es: ¿cómo hacer para que un comentario nuevo realizado en una pregunta antigua, sea visto por la gente para que pueda así ser respondido?

Comment: Muy interesante. Acabo de hacer un vistazo rápido y existe una pregunta/respuesta faq en Meta SE: [Getting attention for unanswered questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7046/182862)

Comment: Independientemente de cómo obtener atención en una pregunta antigua, leyendo tu comentario, estoy convencido de que es una pregunta nueva. Sin duda creo que deberías formular una pregunta y, en todo caso, podrías poner un enlace a tu pregunta anterior como referencia

Comment: Muchas gracias a los dos  Creo que voy a crear una pregunta nueva

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esto está descrito en [What can cause a question to be bumped?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48579/209901), esto es, *¿Qué puede hacer que una pregunta se reflote?*

**Las siguientes acciones hacen que una pregunta sea reflotada**:

- Añadir una respuesta nueva
- Editar o reetiquetar la pregunta, o editar una respuesta* **
- Abrir una recompensa
- Reabrir la pregunta (en caso que estuviera cerrada)
- El usuario Comunidad la reflota bajo unas condiciones determinadas (básicamente, tiene al menos una respuesta con una puntuación de 0 y ninguna con puntuación de 1 o más)

**Las siguientes acciones NO hacen que una pregunta sea reflotada:**

- Eliminación o recuperación de una pregunta o una de sus respuestas.
- Votos positivos o negativos a la pregunta, alguna de las respuestas o algún comentario.
- Reportes.
- Creación o eliminación de comentarios en alguna de las publicaciones.
- Ediciones pendientes.
- Aceptación de una respuesta.
- Protección o desprotección de la pregunta.

---

Como ves, añadir un comentario está en el segundo bloque, por lo que es normal que la pregunta no se reflotara.

> Entonces mi pregunta aquí es: ¿cómo hacer para que un comentario nuevo realizado en una pregunta antigua, sea visto por la gente para que pueda así ser respondido?

El autor de la publicación en la que comentas recibirá una notificación. Si lo que quieres es informar a más gente, lo más probable es que debas editar tu pregunta para dar más detalles. Y como acabamos de ver, eso reflotará tu pregunta.

En general, si tienes que explicar tu pregunta en comentarios, considera editarla para clarificar lo que quieres preguntar.

Comment: Pendiente de revisar la traducción y de añadir las notas a pie de página * y **

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: @Gonzalo si esto responde a tu pregunta, por favor considera **[aceptarla](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** haciendo click en el **✔️**, que está bajo las flechas de votación, a la izquierda de la respuesta (no se te descuenta nada por eso y da cierre -no definitivo- a la publicación).

Comment: Las dos respuestas responden a mi pregunta. ¿Puedo calificar positivamente ambas?

Comment: @Gonzalo ¿a qué te refieres? Si quieres comentarle algo a Mariano, utiliza `@Mariano` para que reciba él la notificación. Por otra parte, lo que comentas aquí es una vez más algo que no tiene que ver con lo que preguntaste; acostúmbrate a ceñir tu pregunta a lo que preguntaste y a abrir nuevas preguntas si tienes nuevas dudas que ya no son la misma.